# Need help finding test cases for the counting rectangle problem

Tags: python, algorithm, unit-testing, math

I have this problem:

Given a list of points in Euclidean coordinates, count the number of distinct, non-zero area rectangles can be formed by any 4 points in the input list (Axis-alignment does not matter)

I hope you guys can find edge cases to attack my solution.

This is my code: https://pastebin.com/fzzJEwY1

```
def countRectangles(intPoints):
    ans = 0
    
    def getDistance(point1, point2):
        x1, y1 = point1[0], point1[1]
        x2, y2 = point2[0], point2[1]
        
        return (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)
    
    def getMidPoint(point1, point2):
        x1, y1 = point1[0], point1[1]
        x2, y2 = point2[0], point2[1]
        midPoint = ((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2)
        
        return midPoint
    
    def intToFloatList(points):
        for i, point in enumerate(points):
            curX, curY = point[0], point[1]
            points[i] = (float(curX), float(curY))
        return points
    
    distanceMidPoint_PointsMap = {}
    
    points = intToFloatList(intPoints)
    
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            nextPoint = points[j]
            
            curSqrdDistance = getDistance(point, nextPoint)
            curMidPoint = getMidPoint(point, nextPoint)
            key = (curSqrdDistance, curMidPoint)
            
            if key not in distanceMidPoint_PointsMap:
                distanceMidPoint_PointsMap[key] = set()
            distanceMidPoint_PointsMap[key].add((point, nextPoint))
              
    for key, val in distanceMidPoint_PointsMap.items():
        if len(val) > 1:
            ans += len(val)
    return ans // 2
```

I have tried both axis-aligned and non-axis-aligned test cases and my solution passed.

Comment: *"I don't know if this is the correct solution"*: then this is off-topic.

Comment: Could you clarify "Count the number of rectangles"? From one point to another ? Between 4 points? If so, to what precision? Do rectangles with zero width count? Etc.

Comment: Start with the most basic cases you can. For example, a list of one point should return 0. Similarly, lists of 2 and 3 points should always return 0. Now create different lists of 4 points. One that doesn't create a rectangle at all, one that creates an axis-allined rectangle and one that creates a rectangle whose sides are not axis aligned. Continue creating more complex cases from there.